# Laplace Transform for differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

In the text, I'm given with the following system of differential equations:

$$y_1'=-y_1+4y_2$$
$$y_2'=3y_1-2y_2$$

where $y_1(0)=3$ and $y_2(0)=4$

In the answer book, by doing Laplace transform it obtains the following system of differential equations:

$$(s-2)Y_1+3Y_2=1$$
$$-Y_1+(s+2)Y_2=0$$

How did it calculate this?

Comment: Then you can regard $s$ as a constant to solve the linear system for $Y_1$ and $Y_2$. Finally, you just perform Laplace inverse transform on $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ together with the initial values to get $y_1$ and $y_2$.

Comment: How does it get $(s-2)Y_1+3Y_2=1$? @Bernard Pan

Answer (score 1):

It's a typo. The correct LT for the system is as follows:
\begin{align*}
sY_1-y_1(0)&=-Y_1+4Y_2\\
sY_2-y_2(0)&=3Y_1-2Y_2\\ \\
sY_1-3&=-Y_1+4Y_2\\
sY_2-4&=3Y_1-2Y_2\\ \\
(s+1)Y_1-4Y_2&=3\\
-3Y_1+(s+2)Y_2&=4.
\end{align*}
Then continue.

Comment: The next step would be performing the inverse Laplace transform? @Adrian Keister

Comment: Nope. You need to solve for $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ first. Then you'd invert the LT.

Comment: Would I use matrix to solve for $Y_1$ and $Y_2$?

Comment: It's a linear system of two equations in two unknowns. You can use any valid method you want, and there are many. Certainly there are matrix methods galore.